# How to delete an image from device in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-gallery

I am creating an app that lets user select an image from gallery and store it in my DB.
I am successful in doing that.

Now I want that selected image to be deleted from phone storage also.
how do I do it then?

I might even want to restore it later in users gallery.

This is what I do to get image from gallery.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) 
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 42:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try
                {
                    inputStream = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    int maxHeight = 1920;
                    int maxWidth = 1920;
                    float scale = Math.min(((float) maxHeight / bm.getWidth()), ((float) maxWidth / bm.getHeight()));
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale);
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                    saveImageToInternalStorage(bitmap, getFileName(uri));
                    bm.recycle();
                    bitmap.recycle();
                    finishActivity(42);
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

This is the Uri path I'm getting

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A5857
```

my onActivityResult looks like this:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 42:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try
                {
                    inputStream = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    int maxHeight = 1920;
                    int maxWidth = 1920;
                    float scale = Math.min(((float) maxHeight / bm.getWidth()), ((float) maxWidth / bm.getHeight()));
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale);
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                    saveImageToInternalStorage(bitmap, getFileName(uri));

                    bm.recycle();
                    bitmap.recycle();
                    finishActivity(42);
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null); is sufficient for Android Q.

Comment: requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission() -> Gives me this error and image is not deleted @blackapps

Comment: Please post an onActivityResult function where you only try to delete the selected image. And tell there which Android version.

Comment: Not Working @blackapps

Comment: You did post nothing.

Comment: Sorry @blackapps, I've Updated my question

Comment: You only reposted the same code. Please read what i asked.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about this same question [Delete image file from device programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39530663/delete-image-file-from-device-programmatically)  Maybe you can get a solution from there.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public static boolean delete(final Context context, final File file) {
      final String where = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?";
       final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
            file.getAbsolutePath()
     };
   final ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
   final Uri filesUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
   contentResolver.delete(filesUri, where, selectionArgs);

if (file.exists()) {

    contentResolver.delete(filesUri, where, selectionArgs);
}
return !file.exists();
```

}

Comment: where do i write this?

Comment: add this into any class and call it where you want like create classs ImageDelete and paste this code and call where you want to delete the image. if you have Uri than convert Uri into file than call it

Comment: What is this here ("external")

Comment: its storage location external and internal